# How to select mandatory character when generating random password with ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I create a random password with Ansible. **4 characters in length**.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    pwd_alias: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=4 chars=ascii_letters,digits,hexdigits,punctuation' ) }}"

  user: root
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Sifre= {{pwd_alias}}

    - debug:
        msg: Sifre= {{pwd_alias}}

    - debug:
        msg: Sifre= {{pwd_alias}}

    - debug:
        msg: Sifre= {{pwd_alias}}
```

I want it to be password  example. **I want the output to look like this example.**

```
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Sifre= Z/bO"
}

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Sifre= a_4G"
}

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Sifre= 9a&0"
}

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Sifre= d.2C"
}
```

1. ascii_letters = 1
2. hexdigits = 1
3. digits = 1
4. punctuation = 1

I want him to generate a random password like this. But what the system produces sometimes changes. Sometimes there are no digits, sometimes there is no punctuation. I want these 4 features to be absolutely.

￼
ansible version =  2.7.10

This is how the outputs are

```
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Sifre= Z/bh"
}

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Sifre= a_-G"
}

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Sifre= 9ad0"
}

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Sifre= d.aC"
}
```

**How do I get each character? Thank you so much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the passwords in a separate file. Get random character from each set and create *pwd_alias_list*. Then *shuffle* and *join* the list.

```
$ cat generate-password-4.yml
- set_fact:
    pwd_alias_list: []
- set_fact:
    pwd_alias_list: "{{ pwd_alias_list + [
                        lookup('password', '/dev/null length=1 chars=' ~ item) ]
                        }}"
  loop:
    - ascii_letters
    - digits
    - hexdigits
    - punctuation
- set_fact:
    pwd_alias: "{{ pwd_alias_list|shuffle|join('') }}"
```

The tasks below

```
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: generate-password-4.yml
    - debug:
        var: pwd_alias
    - include_tasks: generate-password-4.yml
    - debug:
        var: pwd_alias
    - include_tasks: generate-password-4.yml
    - debug:
        var: pwd_alias
    - include_tasks: generate-password-4.yml
    - debug:
        var: pwd_alias
```

give

```
"pwd_alias": "ld(9"
"pwd_alias": "2R`9"
"pwd_alias": "O5(0"
"pwd_alias": "2>z5"
```

It's possible to make the generation of the password more flexible and create a list of the characters' sets *my_char_specs* and number of the repetitions *my_repeat*

```
$ cat generate-password.yml
- set_fact:
    pwd_alias_list: []
- set_fact:
    pwd_alias_list: "{{ pwd_alias_list + [
                        lookup('password', '/dev/null length=1 chars=' ~ item.0) ]
                        }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ my_char_specs }}"
    - "{{ range(0, my_repeat)|list }}"
- set_fact:
    pwd_alias: "{{ pwd_alias_list|shuffle|join('') }}"
```

The task below repeat the random choice from four sets four times

```
  vars:
    my_char_specs:
      - ascii_letters
      - digits
      - hexdigits
      - punctuation
    my_repeat: 4
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: generate-password.yml
    - debug:
        var: pwd_alias
```

and gives

```
"pwd_alias": "8=3[9BD(7?3bJ5y3"
```

Comment: Thanks. @vladimir-botka 
This is a solution if length is 4 thanks. So how do I get it because the length is 12?
Sample:

**318)#:izf865**
producing in this way. But I

**6#f:83)5Z18**

I expect it to be mixed in style.
If;
pwd_alias: "{{lookup ('password', '/ dev / null length = 12 chars = ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits, punctuation')}}"
If I can make it mandatory with this line I will produce as I want.
chars = ascii_letters: digits: hexdigits: punctuation
chars = ascii_letters-digits-hexdigits-punctuation
I tried this style, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Fit the variables to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. @vladimir-botka 
That was the solution. Respects

Answer (score 1):

This solution works, you need to generate each type chars separately then concatenate them :

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    pwd_alias_digit1: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=1 chars=ascii_letters' ) }}"
    pwd_alias_digit2: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=1 chars=digits' ) }}"
    pwd_alias_digit3: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=1 chars=hexdigits' ) }}"
    pwd_alias_digit4: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=1 chars=punctuation' ) }}"
    pwd_alias: "{{ pwd_alias_digit1 + pwd_alias_digit2 + pwd_alias_digit3 + pwd_alias_digit4 }}"

  user: root
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Sifre= {{pwd_alias}}

    - debug:
        msg: Sifre= {{pwd_alias}}

    - debug:
        msg: Sifre= {{pwd_alias}}

    - debug:
        msg: Sifre= {{pwd_alias}}
```

Another way is to create your own password [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins) : `my_password`. It's easier to create a new plugin and use it simple in a playbook. It's better and the playbook will remain readable.

Comment: **Thank you so much.** @nelson-g


But here the characters are side by side. I want mixed.

Example: Let the length be 8. With this logic, this happens.

ca #! 35GT

But I don't want that to happen. I want it that way.

c # 3g to! T5

It's ridiculous to do this by defining many variables.
```
pwd_alias: "{{lookup ('password', '/ dev / null length = 12 chars = ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits, punctuation')}}"
```
In this function I want to assign it randomly.

Comment: Create a `my_password` lookup plugin, I updated answer